# Write to process stdin

Tags: scala

How can I get some kind of writeable stream connected to `stdin` (and also readable streams connected to `stdout` and `stderr`) when launching a process via `scala.sys.process` library? Here's the code that doesn't work (doesn't even print debug messages)

```
  val p = Process("wc -l")
  val io = BasicIO.standard(true)

  val lines = Seq("a", "b", "c") mkString "\n"
  val buf = lines.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

  io withInput { w =>
    println("Writing")
    w.write(buf)
  }

  io withOutput { i =>
    val s = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i)).readLine()
    println(s"Output is $s")
  }
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the [**scaladoc** of the `scala.sys.process` _package_](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/sys/process/index.html), they explain that you can create a [`ProcessIO`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/sys/process/ProcessIO.html) _instance_ when running your process. This **object** is basically a _wrapper_ over three functions - two receives an `OutputStream` _(stdout & stdin)_ and the other receives an `InputStream` _(stdin)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I did but can't figure out how to do it. See updated question with code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

First in your snippet you never connect your process with the `io` and never run it.
That can be done like this: `p run io`.

Second, the `withInput` & `withOutput` *methods* return a **NEW ProcessIO** they DON'T mutate the actual, and since you don't assign the return of those calls to a variable, you are doing nothing.

The following snippet fixes both problems, hope it works for you.

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.sys.process._
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

val p = Process("wc -l")
val io =
  BasicIO.standard(true)
    .withInput { w =>
      val lines = Seq("a", "b", "c").mkString("", "\n", "\n")
      val buf = lines.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
      println("Writing")
      w.write(buf)
      w.close()
    }
    .withOutput { i =>
      val s = Source.fromInputStream(i)
      println(s"Output is ${s.getLines.mkString(",")}")
      i.close()
    }

p run io
```

Don't doubt to ask for clarification.

**PS:** it prints `"Output is 3"` - *(Thanks to Dima for pointing the mistake)*.

Comment: It prints "2" rather than "3" because you never output the last end of line.
Try replacing `mkString.("\n")` (which also has a  typo) with `mkString("", "\n", "\n")`

Comment: @Dima ah, you are right, it never prints the end of the third line, I will edit the answer.